# Dirichlet vs Binomial in pymc3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I am having trouble sampling from a Dirichlet/Multinomial distribution with pymc3.
I tried to create a simple test-case to recreate a Beta/Binomial using Dirichlet/Multinomial with n=2, but I can't get it to work.

Below I have some code that works for Binomial but fails for Multinomial.
One of the obvious differences is that the Multinomial model is more constrained: 
i.e. to start, rating is set to 10 in the Binomial model, and [10,10] in the Multinomial.
The pymc3 Dirichlet code does say "Only the first `k-1` elements of `x` are expected" but only arrays of shape 2 seem to work in my code.

The output shows that `num_friends` and `rating` are being sampled in the Binomial case, but not in the Multinomial case. `friends_ratings` is being sampled in both. Thanks!

Oh, also `Dirichlet('d', np.array([1,1]))` crashes with "Floating point error 8". It only appears to fail when two integers of value 1 are passed in. `np.array([1.,1.])` works.

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

print "TEST BINOMIAL"
with pm.Model() as model:
    friends_ratings = pm.Beta('friends_ratings', alpha=1, beta=2)
    num_friends = pm.DiscreteUniform('num_friends', lower=0, upper=100)
    rating = pm.Binomial('rating', n=num_friends, p=friends_ratings)

    step = pm.Metropolis([num_friends, friends_ratings, rating])
    start = {"friends_ratings":.5, "num_friends":20, 'rating':10}

    tr = pm.sample(5, step, start=start, progressbar=False)    
    print "friends", [tr[i]['num_friends'] for i in range(len(tr))]
    print "friends_ratings", [tr[i]['friends_ratings'] for i in range(len(tr))]
    print "rating", [tr[i]['rating'] for i in range(len(tr))]

print "TEST DIRICHLET"
with pm.Model() as model:
    friends_ratings = pm.Dirichlet('friends_ratings', np.array([1.,1.]), shape=2)
    num_friends = pm.DiscreteUniform('num_friends', lower=0, upper=100)    
    rating = pm.Multinomial('rating', n=num_friends, p=friends_ratings, shape=2)

    step = pm.Metropolis([num_friends, friends_ratings, rating])
    start = {'friends_ratings': np.array([0.5,0.5]), 'num_friends': 20, 'rating': [10,10]}

    tr = pm.sample(5, step, start=start, progressbar=False)    
    print "friends", [tr[i]['num_friends'] for i in range(len(tr))]
    print "friends_ratings", [tr[i]['friends_ratings'] for i in range(len(tr))]
    print "rating", [tr[i]['rating'] for i in range(len(tr))]
```

Output:

```
TEST BINOMIAL
friends [22.0, 24.0, 24.0, 23.0, 23.0]
friends_ratings [0.5, 0.5, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41]
ratingf [10.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0]
TEST DIRICHLET
friends [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0]
friends_ratings [array([ 0.51369621,  1.490608  ]), ... ]
rating [array([ 10.,  10.]), array([ 10.,  10.]), ... ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyMC3 does not automatically normalize the Dirichlet. So far you have to do this explicitly using `simplextransform`. See [here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/dirichlet.py#L10) for an example.

There is an issue of making this transform automatic though: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/315

EDIT (9/14/2015): PyMC3 now automatically transforms the dirichlet distribution (as any other distribution). So you don't need to specify that manually anymore.

Comment: The links are broken :(

Comment: @hgbrian please accept the answer, if it worked for you.